# Is there a way to create an object property from within a method of the same object?

Tags: javascript, methods, properties, javascript-objects

Let's say I have an object `life`:

```
var life = {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 45
};
```

And I call a method `die` 5 seconds after my webpage loads:

```
setTimeout(life.die, 5000);

var life = {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 45,
    die: function() {
        //Die
    }   
};
```

How would I create a property `dead` from within the method `die`? Is it as simple as this?

```
die: function() {
    this.dead = true;
}
```

Or this?

```
die: function() {
    var this.dead = true;
}
```

Or do I need to use something else?

Comment: Why, does it work @Jai?

Comment: @Jai — It would touch `window.dead` not `life.dead` (unless strict mode was in play, in which case it would throw an exception).

Comment: You can't pass `life.die` to `setTimeout` **before** you define `life`! Please *test* your [mcve]s

Comment: That was an example, sorry about that.

Comment: why can't u use life.dead??

Comment: I want to make it only when the method executes.

Comment: die: function() {
    life.dead = true;
}

Comment: But you're accessing `life.dead` within the object `life`, so shouldn't it be `this.dead`? I'm really confused also by the duplicate @Quentin provided, it kind of didn't answer my problem.

Comment: @JBDouble05 — "But you're accessing life.dead within the object life" — No, you're accessing `this.dead` from a function which isn't associated with any object. Look at the duplicate question again. Pay special attention to the bit of the accepted answer headed "What you should know about this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the use the variable name life and assign property dead internally in the function scope it will assign to the life object automatically. If you are using this means it will assign to window object.

```js
     
    
     var life = {
            name: "John Doe",
            age: 45,
            die:  () => {
                life.dead = true;
                console.log(life)
            }
        };
        
        setTimeout(life.die, 5000);
```